# How to attach jstree nodes in form using jquery and receive in MVC Model?

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, jstree

I have a form with multiple Jstree elements. I gathered all jstree nodes using this code:

```
var treeData = $('.jstree').jstree(true).get_json('#', { flat: false });
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(treeData);
```

result is an array of objects. each node has an array of children too.
in server-side I have a model like this:

```
 public class SampleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<JsTreeNode> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and JsTreeNode is like this:

```
public class JsTreeNode
{
    public string id { set; get; } 
    public string text { set; get; }
    public string icon { set; get; }
    public JsTreeNodeState state { set; get; }
    public List<JsTreeNode> children { set; get; }
    public JsTreeNodeLiAttributes li_attr { set; get; }
    public JsTreeNodeAAttributes a_attr { set; get; }
    public string data { get; set; }

    public JsTreeNode()
    {
        state = new JsTreeNodeState();
        children = new List<JsTreeNode>();
        li_attr = new JsTreeNodeLiAttributes();
        a_attr = new JsTreeNodeAAttributes();
    }
}
```

I tried to append jstree data(appending treeData , or jsonData ).

```
var formData = new FormData($("form").get(0));
formData.append('Products', treeData);
```

But nothing were received in server-side.
How can I get this tree structure in Server.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain the general idea?